# Problems with JSP, HTML and connection to SQL server

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

I'm having problems with my programming homework, a JSP project.

I have 2 textfields/inputs and a button. When the button is clicked, I want to send a query to my SQL database that inserts the values entered in the inputs to my query, but I don't know how to connect that.

Here's some code:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee name:</td><td><input id="emp_name" required="" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee phone:</td><td><input id="phone" required="" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <button onclick="sqlQuery()">Add new employee</button>                
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            function sqlQuery {
            <%
                sql = "INSERT INTO `employees` (`employee_name`,`phone`) VALUES ('" + document.getElementById("emp_name") + "','" + document.getElementByID("phone") + ")";
                try {
                s = con.createStatement();
                rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
            }
        </script>
```

So basically, when the button is clicked, I want to send the query with the 2 values of the inputs to create a new employee in this case (I also want to update and delete in the upcoming exercises).

Comment: I don't know how to proceed. I have another button that displays the list with a select * from employees, but i have no problems with that one since there's no input from the website.

Comment: use a real form, and submit it to a servlet. See [this tutorial](http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/A%20servlet%20example.aspx) for example

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I'm not much into the servlets yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this. Run your form action instead of onclick. Below are example for insert and update record to sql, hope it helps :)

### A.jsp

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <FORM  ACTION="B.JSP" METHOD="POST"> //edited part
            Please enter your name:
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="text1">
            <BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="text2">
            <BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
        </FORM>

    </body>
    </html>
```

### B.jsp

```
    <jsp:useBean id="record" scope="page" class="com.home.home.record" />

    String FIRSTNAME = request.getParameter("text1");
    String LASTNAME  = request.getParameter("text2");
    int iRowAffected = 0;

    iRowAffected = record.insert_data(FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME);
    if(iRowAffected == 0) 
    {
           throw new NullPointerException("insert_data");
    }
```

### record.java

```
public int insert_data(String FIRSTNAME, String LASTNAME) throws Exception  
{

   String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM TB_RECORD WHERE FIRSTNAME='"+FIRSTNAME+"' AND LASTNAME='"+LASTNAME+"'";
   stmt = myConn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
   ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(myQuery);

    if(resultSet.next())
    {       
           //UPDATE PART
    }else{
            String myQuery = "INSERT INTO TB_RECORD (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME) VALUES (?,?)";
            pstmt = new PreparedStatementLogable(myConn,myQuery);
            pstmt.setString(1, FIRSTNAME);
            pstmt.setString(2, LASTNAME);
            RowsAffected = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            insertSQLLog("SQL",pstmt.toString(),"","","","");
            pstmt.close();
    }
    return RowsAffected;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! I dont get the record.java at all, your code gives me a lot of problems and i don't think that's what i need :(